# Offsite Custom Conversions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am dealing with several custom conversions in facebook that we created.
However, using graph api I am only able to pull their id and not name.

Is there any way to get the name of the custom conversion?

I went into business manager id;

```
1231412345324?fields=link,id,name,adspixels{audiences{ads{insights{actions},tracking_specs,adlabels}}}
```

[image]

Comment: What endpoint are you attempting to pull those values from? You can receive custom conversion names on the adaccount/customconversions edge

`graph.facebook.com/act_ADACCOUNTID/customconversions?fields=name&access_token=USERACCESSTOKEN`

Comment: pulling it from business manager

Comment: on the graph api, what endpoint are you attempting to pull from?

Comment: I'm using my personal user access token. Check the image if it helps, not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: Ok thanks for the screenshot, i've added a call below, hopefully this will help you achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/BUSINESSMANAGERID/owned_ad_accounts?fields=link,id,name,customconversions{name,id}&access_token=USERACCESSTOKEN`
This will give you a list of your adaccounts in Business Manager and their custom conversion id and name.

[image: First ad account has no custom conversions, second has]

Comment: In a browser, it gives me "You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v2.10." error.

Using graph api, the custom conversion doesn't exist inside owned_ac_accounts, it looks like it's parallel. I think my issue is with authorization at this point. Looks like we know where to get the proper data.

Comment: can you try again with the version number in the url? I've added it to above

Comment: yeah, ive done that as well. it just returns id and name. nothing more.

Comment: the id and name of your custom conversion, or the id and name of your ad accounts?

Comment: id and name of my ad accounts. looks like you're getting back more than I am..hm

Comment: Sorry about the back and forth. I'm guessing your conversions are tied to your business manager as opposed to your ad accounts within the BM?

Does `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/BUSINESSID/customconversions?fields=link,id,name,customconversions{name,id}&access_token=USERACCESSTOKEN` work? Note that your app will need to be tied to your business manager for this to work and you'll use an access token from that same app (as opposed to an access token from graph explorer or similar). Using this approach, I was able to receive a newly created custom conversion from within my BM

Comment: No worries. I haven't setup an app, makes sense why I get this;
(#200) Cannot access an object not managed by the business owning this app.

Would I need to create an app on my personal account or the BM account?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164283/discussion-between-pavlo-morgun-and-patrick-lambe).

Comment: What I've done is created a FB app. Then visited my app settings.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APPID/settings/advanced/ and in there, theres a heading called "Business Manager" with which to tie your app to. I tied my app to my BM and then executing the above call, I was able to receive the custom conversions created in my Business Manager.

An alternative could be to visit https://business.facebook.com/settings/custom-conversions?business_id=BUSINESSID and then assign your custom conversions to an ad account within your business manager. Then you can try my previous call

Comment: But I'll let others chime in if they have more elegant solutions to achieve what you're looking for

Comment: This is interesting. No matter which documentation I go through, I can't figure out how to get the data using the graph api fields. Only your custom code works.

Do you know what fields to choose in the graph api to get the same results without writing the query?

I get to this point;
BUS_ID/owned_ad_accounts?fields=id,name

Afterwards, there's no selections for custom conversion.

Comment: As in you're using the Graph Explorer tool and using the autocompletes on the left handside to choose which fields to append to your query? 

I've never used that autocomplete unfortunately so don't know what dictates which fields show up/don't show up. It could be based on popularity of the fields, or it could simply be that it has not been kept up to date and so new fields aren't added, but I'd be guessing as to why it doesn't appear tbh. edit (or the field is undocumented for that particular edge)

Comment: Is there any way to pull stats from these custom conversions?

Comment: Like just a roll-up of every time it has fired? Or on a campaign by campaign basis? Not sure about the a general "custom_sales has fired 600 times" roll up, but its certainly possible to get insights as to how many times an event fired for a given campaign/adset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164428/discussion-between-pavlo-morgun-and-patrick-lambe).